# NodeJS: Como manter uma lista atualizada acessível entre arquivos

Tags: node.js, express.js

Numa aplicação NodeJS com Express/EJS, estou precisando manter uma lista atualizada e gostaria que sempre que o usuário acessasse minha rota raiz, ou seja a página de INDEX, ele conseguisse ver essa lista já atualizada. Para resumir montei o script abaixo, que é o responsável pela atualização da lista de clientes (mas não tem que ser do jeito que eu montei...):

**Script de atualização da lista de clientes:**

```
// clients_list.js ============================================================
const tls = require('tls');

var clients = [];// Essa será a minha lista de clientes <<<===========
var aa = [{name: "aaaaaaaa"}, {name: "bbbbbbbb"}];

const server = tls.createServer(options, (myObj) => {

   myObj.on('beginEvent', (anotherObj) => {
      // Adiciona um cliente a cada evento
      clients.push(anotherObj);
   })

   myObj.on('endEvent', (anotherObj) => {
      // Remove um cliente a cada evento
      clients.splice(clientes.indexOf(anotherObj), 1);      
   })

});

module.exports = { server, clients, aa };
```

**Arquivo “app.js” do EXPRESS, onde quero que a lista esteja acessível e atualizada sempre:**

```
// app.js do EXPRESS ==========================================================

const app = express();
// vários outros requires...
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

// Importação do servidor "serverCLIENTS.server" e da lista "serverCLIENTS.clients"
const serverCLIENTS = require('./clients_list'); 

// um monte de coisas....


// Minha rota raiz
app.use('/', indexRouter); // <<<========= PRETENDO QUE ESTA ROTA EXIBA A LISTA "serverCLIENTS.clients"


// um monte de coisas....

module.exports = app;
```

**PERGUNTA**: Como faço para que essa lista “clients" se mantenha visível e atualizada em minha aplicação?

Será que o jeito é fazer um *middleware* desse meu script `clients_list.js`?

Comment: Como listas são passadas por referência em JavaScript, qualquer arquivo que fizer require dela, estará acessando a mesma lista. Se o seu *app.js* fizer require da lista, e adicionar um item, esse item também aparecerá para outro arquivo que fizer o require.

Porém há um ponto a se considerados ao se utilizar esse método: Se sua lista for mantida numa variável, ela só existirá enquanto o servidor estiver em pé. Ao se reiniciar o servidor, a lista que estava na memória volátil será perdida. Era essa a dúvida? Desculpa não ficou muito clara.

Comment: Minha dúvida é essa mesma, porém não entendi como tornar essa lista "atualizável" em todos os lugares onde eu fizer o `require`. Por exemplo, no `app.js`, eu consigo acessar a lista de clientes através de `indexRouter.clients`, OK! Porém, como eu torno essa mesma lista visível também no arquivo `index.js` por exemplo. Seu eu fizer um `require` dentro da página `index.js`, será criada uma nova instância da lista e não um apontamento para a lista já existente em `app.js`. Concorda? Não sei se consegui me fazer entender agora, mas puder me ajudar fico muito grato.

Comment: Não, não será criado uma nova instancia. `clients` em `index.js` será a mesma instancia de `clients` em `clients_list.js`.

Comment: Acho que tem alguma coisa a mais que eu não estou conseguindo ver... no início do `client_list.js`, se por exemplo eu incluir `var aa = [{name: "aaaaaaaa"}, {name: "bbbbbbbb"}];`, eu consigo listar esses dados na página de index. Porém, a variável `clients` do `client_list.js` é atualizada num processo assíncrono, ou seja, quando eu executo o `require clients_list.js` no `index.js` por exemplo, essa lista de clientes ainda não possui nenhum item. Aos longo do tempo ela vai sendo incrementada. Só que quando eu atualizo a página de index, nenhum item é mostrado.

Comment: Eu dei uma editada no script e incluir a variável var aa = [{name: "aaaaaaaa"}, {name: "bbbbbbbb"}]; no início. Estes dados eu consigo listar na página de index. Já a variável clients, mesmo depois de incluir itens nela eu não consigo listá-los no index, pois ela só será atualizada depois que o servidor for criado por meio da linha `const server = tls.createServer(options....`. Depois que esse trecho de código for executado não vou conseguir mais listar o conteúdo da variável pois a página index já foi carregada. Acho que é esse o problema que impede de eu ver a lista atualizada.

Comment: @user140828, consegui fazer funcionar sem alterar nada do código que postei inicialmente, porém não consegui encontrar o problema que impedia de funcionar antes. Mas como você disse, realmente o NodeJS NÃO CRIA outra instância do Objeto ao fazer `require` do mesmo arquivo JS em múltiplos scripts (está na documentação inclusive), desde que seja exportado um OBJETO, como eu fiz. Se for exportada uma FUNÇÃO, aí a história é outra. Bom ao menos serviu para eu estudar mais um monte de coisas. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer compartilhar uma propriedade entre vários módulos da sua aplicação, uma forma é voce usar o Singleton Pattern aplicado no node, definindo um módulo que contém a instância única, que será consumido e alterado por diversos outros módulos.

e.g. :

Definindo um singleton com um array:

```
// singleton.js
const names = ['Joana', 'Jorge'];

module.exports.names = names;
```

consumindo ele no módulo A:

```
// singletonconsumer.js
const names = require('./singleton').names;

function seeNames() {
    console.log(names);
}

module.exports.seeNames = seeNames;
```

Consumindo e alterando no módulo B:

```
// index.js 
const names = require('./singleton').names;
const seeNames = require('./singletonconsumer').seeNames;

print();

names.push('fernanda');

print();

function print() {
    console.log(names);
    seeNames();
}
```

O resultado do print:

[image: printando antes e depois da alteração]

Exemplo rodando: https://repl.it/@spartanroger/node-patterns

Link sobre patterns com Node : [Rising stack NodeJS and Design Patterns](https://blog.risingstack.com/fundamental-node-js-design-patterns/)

Comment: Bem legal! O problema é que meu módulo `clients_list.js` demora um pouco para carregar a variável array `clients` e é um processo assíncrono assim como quase tudo em Javascript. Então quando eu faço um `const serverCLIENTS = require('./clients_list');`, a variável importada `serverCLIENTS.clients` ainda está vazia pois não houve tempo de ser populada. Então estou precisando de algum processo paralelo que atualiza a variável... Eu preciso que sempre que o usuário acessar a rota raiz, seja exibido o conteúdo atual da variável `serverCLIENTS.clients`.

Comment: Realmente, o processo do Node é assíncrono e isso pode dar problemas. Duas alternativas aí, ou utilizar uma lib pra tornar o node síncrono, como a sync, ou não enviar a lista direto na rota raíz, mas sim expor um endpoint com essa informação e a aplicação efetuar uma chamada AJAX, que também é assíncrono! O que acha?

Comment: Para falar a verdade não tenho uma opinião formada. Sou inexperiente em Javascript/NodeJS e não sei fazer nada disso. Estou estudando agora o uso de Promisses e Bluebird para saber se é possível adaptar meu código, mas também não tenho uma opinião formada a respeito. Se tiver alguma coisa aí sobre isso ou mesmo algum exemplo sobre suas sugestões seria de grande ajuda. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Entendi, sem problemas. Eu recomendo que a página raiz faça uma requisição HTTP para outra rota e assim obter a lista de forma separada. Assim você pode tratar o carregamento da informação de maneira assíncrona na página, com loading e tudo. Agora se você quiser que a página seja atualizada quando a lista for atualizada, aí recomendaria o uso de web sockets. https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

Comment: No lado do Cliente eu tenho um dispositivo IoT que faz as requisições via socket, como você bem observou. Eu já tentei sem sucesso usar esse pacote WebSocket com minha aplicação, que precisa ter uma comunicação segura com certificado. Não consegui fazer funcionar nem sem o certificado para falar a verdade. De qualquer forma, a comunicação socket como eu fiz já funciona. O que não sei, que seria o primeiro passo, é ler a variável `clients` após ter sido preenchida com a lista de clientes. Num segundo momento, talvez, pode ser que eu precise atualizar a lista em tempo real.

Comment: Sobre a questão de fazer com um requisição em rota separada, pode até funcionar para uma página onde os dados serão exibidos, porém não sei como isso funcionaria num script qualquer onde não estou fazendo requisições, por exemplo, se eu quisesse ler a mesma lista `clients` dentro o script `app.js`.

Comment: Sendo uma solução pra IoT não tenho expertise, não sei se WebHook ou WebSockets são o ideal, já que o device não tem muita banda pra comunicação...talvez utilizar um protocólo específico para IoT para a comunicação entre esses scripts...

Comment: Sim, mas em relação à comunicação não há problema. Isso já está superado, apesar dos poucos recursos oferecidos pelo processador desses tipos de hardware. Implementei um modelo proprietário de comunicação, da maneira mais simples possível, apenas com socket e um protocolo meu também. Existem muitas coisas prontas, tal como o protocolo MQTT, suportado pela maioria dos hardwares, ainda assim eu esbarraria no mesmo problema, o qual está do lado do servidor. Mas obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: estudando sobre o uso de Singleton acabei encontrando este tópico que me chamou muito a atenção pela quantidade de informações e advertências sobre o uso desse tipo de recurso. Veja aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179109/singleton-pattern-in-nodejs-is-it-needed

Comment: Como foi dito no link que você enviou, se for exportado um objeto como no exemplo que postei, funciona bem. Se for exportado uma função pode gerar problemas com o cache do node.